# ServiceDescription cannot handle wsdl import

Tags: web-services, wcf, wsdl

**Issue description:**

I want dynamic consume WCF service in the code. Using ServiceDescription to read wsdl's definition, but for element of wsdl:import, it cannot read element from location source.

**Question**

I would like to know that does any class implemented by Microsoft can read all import files? The framework should provided such methods, but I am not master it now. 
Thanks.

Comment: *Using ServiceDescription to read wsdl's definition* - what does this mean? What is ServiceDescription? Is it an executable? A class library?

Comment: ServiceDescription which is a class library. [Help on using ServiceDescription with WSDLs that contain import directives](http://forums.asp.net/t/1099060.aspx?Help+on+using+ServiceDescription+with+WSDLs+that+contain+import+directives) is same issue with me, I can write code to merge the definition into one object, but it's not the best practices. This should be framework responsibility to merge imports for all split wsdl file,

Comment: If imports don't resolve, does that mean the import targets are missing, or just not at expected location?

Comment: no, the element of wsdl import has valid target source. this issue is because that WCF provider who use different namespace on service contract and service behavior. so it is split by WCF for namespace reason. But at the client side, we don't use svcutil or wsdl to generate proxy class. we are manually do it in the code at runtime. As you can see if we use svcutil.exe to generate proxy class file, it does resolve import issue. Or run the url on SoapUI, that's works also. therefore that's why I don't want handle this case manually in the code.

Comment: OK, and this answer (http://forums.asp.net/post/1740748.aspx) did not help you?

Comment: Currently, as workaround solution, I have been use the same way with that link, anyway thanks for you help, Tom :). yesterday I have reviewed the related open source code where Microsoft did public their source code on the web, it seems doesn't provide such methods. So we only do it manually.